# What's the meaning of this part of code?

Tags: c++, c

Can somebody say what's the meaning of this code?

```
void (* const rvt[])(void) = {
  (void (*) (void))((unsigned long)&__STACK_END), // The initial stack pointer
  xkg_som,                                  // The reset handler
  xnt_ISR,                                  // The NMI handler
  FaultISR,                                 // The hard fault handler
  IntDefaultHandler,                        // The MPU fault handler
  bgs_stm,                                  // The bus fault handler
  IntDefaultHandler,                        // The usage fault handler
  0,                                        // Reserved
  0,                                        // Reserved
  IntDefaultHandler,                        // The MPU fault handler
};
```

I actually don't understand it.

Comment: trying to cast an actual address to a function pointer type... to use it later...but i'm confused of the types there...

Comment: This looks like an [interrupt vector table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interrupt_vector_table).

Comment: For future reference, you can always try [cdecl](http://cdecl.ridiculousfish.com/?q=void+%28*+const+rvt%5B%5D%29%28void%29) for a hint.

Comment: Is this supposed to be C or C++? Pick **one**!

Comment: @SouravGhosh: That the vector table of an ARM Cortex-M3 or 4 CPU. The only thing wrong is using `unsigned int` here. That cast should be `uintptr_t`, but is actually unnecessary. But yes, that is indeed beyond the C standard.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> ```
> void (* const rvt[])(void)
> ```

Means (courtesy of [cdecl.org](http://cdecl.org/)):

> declare rvt as array of const pointer to function (void) returning void

---

```
T foo = {
    value1,
    value2,
    value3 // ...
};
```

This is [aggregate initialization](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/aggregate_initialization)[1] of the array. Furthermore, this means that the declaration of `rvt` is a definition.

---

> ```
> &__STACK_END
> ```

The addresof operator takes the memory address of the variable.

> ```
> (unsigned long)&__STACK_END)
> ```

The address is casted to `unsigned long` type.

> ```
> (void (*) (void))((unsigned long)&__STACK_END)
> ```

The converted value is again casted to pointer to function (void) returning void, which is the type of function pointers stored in the array.

---

The rest of the initialized values of the array may be either function names, function pointers or something that can be implicitly converted to a function pointer such as lambdas.

Comment: There is no "copy-list-initialisation" in C.

Comment: It is in fact a plain old array initializer list. Constructors are obviously not called, nor "lambdas", since this is an interrupt vector table. There's nothing to calculate and nothing that should be done in run-time.

Comment: @Lundin To clarify my answer, it assumes no context since none was provided. I'm not describing what the variables are (since I don't know that); I describe what the could be, given just the code and no context. Concerning your last sentence, isn't there constant initialization at the start of the run-time (assuming the table is static)?

Comment: @user2079303 No of course there will be no constant initalization in run-time. It is for a microcontroller with true NVM, not some RAM-based PC... Constants are programmed into flash.

Answer (score 3):

```
void (* const rvt[])(void)
```

This defines a const array named "rvt". Its elements are pointers to a void function without arguments.

This array is then initialised with a brace initialiser list. So all the other lines are elements of this array. The first one is a pointer to __STACK_END, which apparently is of the wrong type and thus needs to be casted into the right type (it will first be casted into unsigned long and then into the right function-type pointer).

Btw: The code is incomplete, since the brace is not closed, or maybe your formatting went wrong, since the last comment contains the closing brace?

Comment: `This defines a const array named "rvt"` So the `Array` here is `const` and is not a `const pointer`?

Comment: @Michi: Yes. The functions themselves are constant implicitly (you cannot apply `const` to a function itself).  I would become more clear using a `typedef` for the function (pointer).

Comment: @Olaf That was my point too. But why does this Answer make it different?

Comment: @Michi:; Ah, now I see your point. Well, yes, strictly speaking the pointers are `const`. But that means implicitly that the array itself is `const`, too. You cannot qualify the array itself, only the elements.

Comment: @olaf Thats why I was asking. Because for me, I see a huge difference between,  `declare rvt as array of const pointer to function` and `This defines a const array named "rvt"`

Comment: @Michi: Theoretically you are right. But practically it does not make a difference (see reasoning in my comment). The `const`-ness of the array results from the `const`-ness of its elements.

Comment: @Olaf One thing which I like here on SO are those things like: `Theoretically you are right`. This is what makes SO different from other Web/Sites. The way how ppl here are contradicting they self make SO a big place where you get knowledge.

Comment: @Michi: Would "strictly speaking you are right" better suit you? Whatever it is, the array **is** `const`, because its elements are `const`. You just stop one link in the chain of proof too early.

Answer (score 1):

It defines an array of pointers to functions, which take take no arguments and return void. Then the array is initialized with the addresses of some registers in memory, which are casted to function pointers.

It looks like interrupt vector table used for embedded programming.

Comment: The array is most likely a vector table indeed, but it is initialized from compile-time constants and functions, not from registers in memory. Initializing from registers wouldn't be possible, since the array is read-only.

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be an interrupt vector table for an ARM Cortex M microcontroller.

[image]

One special feature in ARM Cortex compared to most other MCUs, is that it has the stack pointer set before program start. Other MCUs tend to set it in run-time.

So the very first entry in the table is the value which the stack pointer should be set to at program start-up. `__STACK_END` is likely some constant obtained from the linker. The cast `(void (*) (void))` turns it into a function pointer. Casting from a pointer to an int to a function pointer is a bit questionable, but it will likely work on most embedded C compilers, despite the C standard frowning at such.

The rest of the entries are function addresses to interrupt service routines (functions). That is, they are the same thing as function pointers. You can initialize a function pointer by giving it the name of a function.

The whole vector table is therefore declared as an array of function pointers, where each function has the signature `void func (void)`. The `*const` declaration means that the function pointers themselves are read-only. Meaning they will get allocated in flash, as is proper for a vector table. Vector tables are usually allocated at a fixed, reserved address in flash.

A prettier way to write the same code would be this:

```
typedef void (isr_t)(void);

isr_t* const [] = {
  (isr_t* const)((uintptr_t)&__STACK_END),  // The initial stack pointer
...
```

`uintptr_t` is a large enough integer type, guaranteed to be able to hold an address, unlike `unsigned long`.